# Python: os.walk() with enumeration

Tags: python

In Python, I want to go list all the directories in a root directory, and print out the directory number together with the directory. I then want to print out the files in that directory.

The code would be something like:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    print "Directory " + str(dir_num) + " = " subdir
    for (file_num, file) in enumrate(files):
        print "File " + str(file_num) + " = " file
```

But how do can I get a value for `dir_num`, i.e. the number of the directory in the root directory? I know how to do this to print the file number, using `enumerate()`, but I'm unsure as to how to apply this to `os.walk()`...

Answer (score 8):

You can still use `enumerate()`:

```
for dirnum, (subdir, dirs, files) in enumerate(os.walk(root_dir)):
```

You need the parentheses around `subdir, dirs, files` because `enumerate()` will return only two items: the index and the tuple `subdir, dirs, files`.